# FabricJS: Adding SVG to canvas but invisible on export

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I'm trying to add an SVG to a canvas object with FabricJS and then exporting it to a data url image to let the user save the image, the arrow is shown in the canvas but when I call the toDataURL method and checking the image, it is just an empty image. I also checked the toSVG() method to check if the sag is there but it isn't in the exported SVG.

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghko8kna/) to demonstrate this.

In the example the arrow is shown when the button is clicked and I call `canvas.toDataURL()` and checked it in my browser and that shows an empty image. Calling `canvas.toSVG()` also returns an SVG without the arrow svg as seen in the fiddle.

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the calls in the callback otherwise they occur before the data has loaded e.g.

```
  fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgString, function(results, options) {
    var arrow = results[0];
    canvas.add(arrow);
    console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
    console.log(canvas.toSVG()); 
  });
```

Or [as a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/kvnz5ru1/)